# How to use name "type" for a key field?

Tags: haskell

I would like to use this data type in Haskell:

```
data DirTree = DirTree {
                name     :: FilePath,
                type    :: Text,
                children :: Maybe [DirTree]
              }
```

But the name `type` is not accepted by Haskell, because it is a reserved keyword.

Is there a way to use it ? Since `type` is not an object exported from a package, I can't solve this issue by doing `import ... hiding (type)`.

Comment: `type` is a reserved work, I don't think there is any way to use it. I think standard procedure would be to add an underscore (like `_type` or `type_`), or choose a different name.

Comment: why not `type'` ?

Comment: Yes, `_type` is what I'm currently doing.

Comment: @BabraCunningham What is it supposed to do ?

Comment: Thank you for the edit @Lee. Using Google Translate to translate the French "réservé",  I understood that the meaning of "reserved" is "shy" only ^^

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent The apostrophe character is valid in identifiers, so adding it would function the same as using an underscore. It's largely personal preference - most people I think have a convention for when they choose to use underscores and apostrophes.

Comment: I realize this is more of a question in an of itself, but does Haskell have an established convention for this?  (Python, for example, tends to use `keyword_` as the name of a variable that conflicts with `keyword`.)

Comment: @chepner The most prominent example I'm familiar with is probably `blaze-html` which chooses an underscore suffix in the cases when HTML attributes correspond to reserved words. I would be interested if anybody knows of other popular libraries that make the same or contradicting choices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `type` is a keyword in Haskell used to define type synonyms. Look: [type is a keyword](https://wiki.haskell.org/Keywords#type).

Also tested this on ghc-8.0.1, and it worked.

```
    data DirTree = DirTree {
            name     :: FilePath,
            _type    :: Text,
            children :: Maybe [DirTree]
          }
```

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted, but do you mean it's not possible ?

Comment: I believe that is not possible to use keywords as record fields. But it should be possible to use `_type` or some other variants.

Answer (score 0):

As you have gathered, you can't use a reserved word as an identifier.

---

What I like to do is prefix my names in record syntax with the type name, such as this:

```
data DirTree = DirTree { dirTreeName     :: FilePath,
                         dirTreeType     :: Text,
                         dirTreeChildren :: Maybe [DirTree] }
```

This also prevents potential name clashes with other functions with common names.

Alternatively, as it's pointed out in the comments, you could add a symbol like `_` or `'` to your name to distinguish it from the keyword.